# How to prevent gerrit replication ref/changes/* to mirror git repository

Tags: git, gerrit

My project is using built-in replication of Gerrit 2.4.2 to mirror content to another git repo.

My configuration looks like below,

```
[remote "another-git-server"]
  url = mirorserver.com:/git/projects/${name}
  push = +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
  push = +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
```

However Gerrit replicates all **refs/changes/*** to mirror git repo. I don't want to replicate those internal review changes to another git server.

Is there any way to prevent gerrit replicate those references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs at http://gerrit-documentation.googlecode.com/svn/Documentation/2.4.2/config-replication.html, pushing refs/heads/* and refs/tags/* will not push anything from refs/changes/*.  If you are positive this is what you are seeing, please file a bug at http://code.google.com/p/gerrit/issues/list.

One other work-around you could try - specify an authGroup in the config and create a group which doesn't have read permissions on refs/changes/*

Comment: There is a [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=1276&q=replication&colspec=ID%20Type%20Stars%20Milestone%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary) to enable new replication config without restarting gerrit. I can't remember whether I restarted Gerrit or not after changing push url of replication. I already restart gerrit to see whether it works. @brand, thanks for your hint. :)

Comment: Just FYI - with Gerrit 2.5 (not yet released) this has been done.  The replication feature is now a Gerrit plugin and can be reloaded to pull in new configuration settings without restarting the server.

Comment: I think it's caused by I didn't restart gerrit server even I used right configuration.